# Changing state of a child element from App component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've currently got an App component setup like so:

```
var App = React.createClass({
  test: function() {
    return null
  },
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Navbar>
          <NavButton text="Test Button" onClick={this.test} />
        </Navbar>
        <PopupMenu />
        <Map />
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```

As you can see on the navbutton I have a click event setup, however when it's clicked I would like it to show that PopupMenu component by changing the PopupMenu's state.visible to true. However, I do not want to 'hardcode' this in the navbutton as different buttons should be able to trigger different events.

On another note, when that menu then appears, how would I have a button in that menu call a function on the Map component? To give it some context, the button will pass geojson to the map or trigger an ajax call on the map to return geojso so that it can map data.

If that didn't make any sense, please ask me and I will explain further.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`refs`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/more-about-refs.html):

```
var PopupMenu = React.createClass({
    [...]
    show: function () { [...] } 
    [...]
});

var App = React.createClass({
  test: function() {
    this.refs['popop'].show();
  },
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Navbar>
          <NavButton text="Test Button" onClick={this.test} />
        </Navbar>
        <PopupMenu ref="popup" />
        <Map />
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, thank you. Is this the best way of doing it, or a not-so-good work around?

Comment: Is there anyway to complete this inline? When I try and do <NavButton text="Test Button" onClick={this.refs['modal'].toggleShow();} /> I get 'Cannot read property 'toggleShow' of undefined'.

Comment: At the time of `render` you have no access to `refs`. Use this: `onClick={e => this.refs['modal'].toggleShow()}`.

Comment: Great, thank you. Could you explain why the e => resolves this please?

Comment: `e => this.refs['modal'].toggleShow()` is [a short syntax](https://github.com/lukehoban/es6features#arrows) to write `function (e) { this.refs['modal'].toggleShow(); }.bind(this)`, that is `this.refs` will be queried after `render` method returns.

Answer (score 0):

if you don't want to use `ECMA-6` please re-factor the code or use a transpiler

```
import React,{Component} from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'; //npm install react-dom --save
import update from 'react-addons-update' //npm install react-addons-update --save
//import other required stuff


class App extends Component{

  constructor() {
    super(...arguments);
    //set the initial state of componenet
    this.state={
    show:false,
    mapData: {}
  }
}

  test(){
    //toggle visibility
    let newState= update( this.state.show,{$set:!this.state.show});

    this.setState(
      {
        show:newState,
        mapData:this.state.mapData
    });
  }

  getSetMapData(){
   //...fetch data for map
   // and alter the state
   let newState= update(this.state.mapData,{$set:fetched_data});
   this.setState(
     {
        show:this.state.show,
        mapData:newState
     });
  }

  render() {

    if(this.state.show){
      //don't use [let] here 
      var pM=(<PopupMenu mapDataFetch={this.getSetMapData.bind(this)} />) ;
    }

    return (
      <div>
        <Navbar>
          <NavButton text="Test Button" onClick={this.test.bind(this)} />
        </Navbar>
        {pM} //change here
        <Map mapData={this.state.mapData}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
ReactDOM.render(<App />,document.getElementById('elem'));
```

You are bulking a single component too much, try to decompose your components. For example you can move the `NavButton` as a child of `Navbar` component in its rendering function.

It is best to let the outermost component be state-full and pass the state as input to children via properties following the hierarchy `Parent(state-full)->Children(also Parent)->Children...`. for example `App`'s `getSetMapData` function is passed down to `PopupMenu` as it's property

```
//and further in render function of `PopupMenu` you can pass 
//it to button nested in `PopupMenu` 

<button onClick={this.props.mapDataFetch}>Map's Data</button>
```

Comment: Where can I find the best documentation for es6?